# Who play important role in multicast of video on SharePoint Site

Tags: video

For multicast of video on SharePoint Site, which of the following will play a important role?

[1] The Server hosting the SharePoint Site? 
[2] The SharePoint Server itself 
[3] The video player on the SharePoint Site 
[4] The video itself.